# Why do you have to have votes on a tag before you can suggest a synonym?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Looking through the pages of tags I noticed many that are the same. An example are the tags **usaf** and **us-air-force**. At this point nobody has made a synonym for them. I was surprised to find that I can't even **suggest** a synonym since I don't have 5 up-votes in the tag (and likely never will). I can see having to have activity in that tag to *vote* on a synonym but if you notice one that needs a synonym you should at least be able to suggest it.

Answer (score 10):

The general idea is that if you don't have at least 5 up-votes in a tag you *probably* don't have enough domain-specific knowledge to be suggesting synonyms. A good question (or answer) can easily garner the 5 upvotes required to meet this threshold.

Of course this leads to edge cases like this one, where it's pretty obvious a synonym should exist but nobody with the necessary upvotes has though of suggesting it yet. For these cases (or really any blatantly-obvious cases) the thing to do is open a Meta post, and usually a moderator will come along and merge the tags. This is also usually faster than the user-driven synonym process.

---

In this case I've merged [usaf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usaf) into [us-air-force](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-air-force), in part because the latter had a more complete tag wiki entry. [usaf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usaf) will remain as a synonym (the expanded form will show up in tag lists, but the short form can be used in searching and adding tags).

Comment: Note that [this is the case on essentially every site, including SO](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms).